# How to import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity in Android studio?

Tags: android, androidx

I have set `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` and I can see some `androidx...` packages, but not `androidx.appcompat.app`.

I guess I need to add something like `implementation 'androidx.appcompat...:v1.0.0'` in my `build.gradle` file, but what is the correct string, or maybe I don't need this?

`Migrate to AndroidX` does not work since I don't have an existed project with support library. I'm about to rewrite an `Acitivty` with action bar and tabs (which is deprecated now) to androidx `AppCompatAcvitiy`.

Thanks.

Comment: @MartinZeitler So can you point out the way from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat since it's not an outdated document?

Comment: There release date of version `1.0.0` is the 7th of November 2018, which is over a year ago, while there where several alpha, beta and rc version before that - which means that it's at least 1-2 years old, which in terms of software isn't new at all. All I'd suggest is to search before asking. If I wouldn' t be too lazy right now, I'd likely be able to close it with several duplicates.

Comment: I actually did searches, my problem was I don't know what's the correct search term. I left Android developing for 6 years, 1 year ago things are new to me and I don't think is old enough for the documents to update. I see my old codes have many things deprecated, so I find replacements, then I am in AppCompactActivity page, it has links to `support library` and `Action Bar` API guide, and I can't find a route to reach a page in the release note rather than in https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/package-summary.

Comment: The correct search term is implementation androidx.appcompat, but I expect there will be a page like developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages for androidx ones. I can't reach such a page, so I thought it's just the document is not written yet. I can't agree the document is in the correct location (it's release note, man) and having enough link to it.

Answer (score 4):

Oh okay, I found it right after I posted my question.

From https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat:

```
dependencies {
    def appcompat_version = "1.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    // For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
}
```